# SQL Query issue 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlplus

I have 2 tables. I want to use them in a query, but I'm having issues with the results.

I have a table for `Games` storing `game_id`, `game_name` and another table with `Releases` information which also has `game_id` as a foreign key. I've setup my keys so not sure why it doesn't work.

```
SELECT Release_date.game_id, game_name
FROM Games,Releases
WHERE release_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-2017' AND '20-JAN-2017'
```

The query works when I'm simply working with 1 table but when I try to add the game_name / Games table in it just gives me every single entry.

> > Version I got working.

```
SELECT game_id
FROM Releases
WHERE release_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-2017' AND '20-JAN-2017'
```

Comment: You haven't specified the join condition in the sql between the tables.

Comment: I'm doubtful that this works at all, but I may be mistaken. Either way, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`/`ON`.

Answer (score 0):

To return the game name from the game_id, you need to join to the Games table:

```
SELECT Games.game_name
     , Releases.release_date
  FROM Releases 
 INNER JOIN Games ON Games.game_id = Releases.game_id
 WHERE Releases.release_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-2017' AND '20-JAN-2017'
```